# passing and enforcing a member function in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I'm trying to create a work queue class (FooQueue) that has:

- a set of function members doing work (do*). Each one of them take one parameter, having the same type (FooItem).
- an 'add' function that takes 2 parameters: one of the above functions, and a FooItem. Most importantly, the add function should only be able to take in a member function of the FooQueue class, rather than a member function of another class with the similar signature

The code compiles when the do function is static, but not when the function is non-static, even though acording to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) the definition of the instance function member is correct.

What should be changed to make it compile/run?

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        FooQueue q = new FooQueue();
        q.add( FooQueue::dos, new FooItem() );    // this compiles
        q.add( q::do1, new FooItem() );           // this does not:
                                                  // does not consider q::do1 'delegate'
                                                  // as taking 2 parameters,
                                                  // with q being the first one
        FooQueue q2 = new FooQueue2();
        q.add( FooQueue2::dos, new FooItem() );   // want this to give compiler error
        q.add( FooQueue2::do1, new FooItem() );   // want this to give compiler error
    }
}

public class FooQueue {
    public static void dos( FooQueue q, FooItem item ) {
        System.out.println( "FooQueue:sdo" );
    }
    public void do1( FooItem item ) {
        System.out.println( "FooQueue:do1" );
    }
    public void add( java.util.function.BiConsumer<FooQueue,FooItem> func, FooItem wi ) {
        System.out.println( "FooQueue:addWorkItem2" );
        func.accept( this, wi );
    }
}
public class FooItem {
}
public class FooQueue2 {
    public static void dos( FooQueue2 q2, FooItem item ) {
        System.out.println( "FooQueue2:sdo" );
    }
    public void do1( FooItem item ) {
        System.out.println( "FooQueue2:do1" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not related to static / non-static method, nor generics, but only to `BiConsumer` definition.

`BiConsumer` requires two parameters, so you need lambda that requires two parameters and doesn't return any.

To fix that, use **instance method reference**:

```
FooQueue q = new FooQueue();
q.add(FooQueue::do1, new FooItem());
```

---

Don't confuse it with static method reference. `FooQueue::do1` is syntatic sugar for lambda:

```
(qInstance, item) -> qInstance.do1(item));
```

This approach allows you to accept only methods from `FooQueue`.

Note that `q:do1` is not compatible with `BiConsumer` as it's converted to:

```
(item) -> q.do1(item)
```

Read more about [Instance method reference](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx#instance-method-reference-of-an-object-of-a-particular-type)

---

**Full example with different classes**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooQueue q = new FooQueue();
        FooQueue2 q2 = new FooQueue2();

        q.add(FooQueue::do1, new FooItem());
        // Equals to:
        q.add((qInstance, item) -> qInstance.do1(item), new FooItem());

        // q.add(FooQueue2::do1, new FooItem());  // not compile
    }
}

class FooQueue {
    void do1(FooItem item) {
        System.out.println("FooQueue:do1");
    }

    void add(BiConsumer<FooQueue, FooItem> func, FooItem wi) {
        System.out.println("FooQueue:addWorkItem");
        func.accept(this, wi);
    }
}

// class that pretends to be FooQueue
class FooQueue2 {
    void do1(FooItem item) {
        System.out.println("FooQueue2:do1");
    }
}

class FooItem {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to enforce FooQueue::add accepting only FooQueue member functions (at compile time)?

Unfortunately, using Consumer<T> will enforce the parameter(s), but not the class membership, which is the root problem I would like to solve.

Comment: @daniel Now I better understood problem you're trying to solve. I've rewritten my answer with appropriate example. Let me know if that helps.